# В С++ нельзя считать Unicode из файла?

Tags: c++, unicode, fstream

Хочу считать из файла символы в Юникоде (UCS-2LE, например), соответственно, в wstring, но ни один знакомый способ не работает. А найденных в интернете "костылей" пока хочется избежать.

Есть решение из комментария ниже - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775437/read-unicode-utf-8-file-into-wstring. Есть вариант с считыванием в char и последующей перекодировкой в нужный многобайтовый тип символов. Даже видел использование WinAPI.

Собственно, вопрос: существует ли очевидный способ считать из файла текст в одной из Unicode-кодировок? Какой-нибудь wcin, только для нестандартных потоков?

Comment: Попробуйте: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10607146/5909792

Comment: Ошибка в первой же строке - систематическое игнорирование возвращаемых значений. `_O_WTEXT` не является допустимым параметром. А проверка того, считалось ли из файла что-то правильно или нет - в приведенном коде отсутствует. И нет, печать в wcout не является такой проверкой.

Comment: @user7860670, хотите поспорить с компилятором о допустимых значениях? Вместо того, чтобы искать ошибки в каждой букве (и видеть их там, где их нет), лучше перечитайте вопрос.

Comment: @gil9red, наверное, это решит мою проблему с чтением текста, но мне интересно, неужели за 11 лет не появилось более очевидного решения, как если бы можно было ограничиться сменой string-параметра в getline  на wstring?

Comment: @Nor, яростно плюсую :) Когда я писал на с++, часто использовал Qt, а там можно перед считыванием указать кодировку https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630156/5909792 . Странно, что в c++ такого явного указания кодировки нет

Comment: В любом языке нельзя читать юникод, это не кодировка. Можно читать utf8, utf16 и кучу других. Поэтому и сложно избегать костылей - надо правильнее вопрос поставить.

Comment: @Nor Компилятор в С++ редко отслеживает допустимость значений. В первой же строке за корректность значений (и за обработку ошибок) отвечает программист, то бишь вы. И да, у вас действительно ошибки практически в каждой строке. Так что вместо танцев с бубном лучше перечитайте мой предыдущий комментарий и отладте код.

Comment: @KoVadim, я это прекрасно понимаю, не учёл в правке, что конкретизирующий текст тоже пропадёт. Но тут прикол в том, что костыли от этого не пропадают.

Comment: @user7860670, и всё-таки я считаю, что заменив _O_U16TEXT на всплывшее в подсказке _O_WTEXT, которое, логично предположить, почти тоже самое и работает так, как предполагалось, при этом не подсвечиваясь, как ошибка, довольно небольшое упущение по сравнению с полным отсутствием функциональности в таком маленьком коде.